# Makefile for building and outputting in a bunch of different folders

Tags: makefile

I have a directory that contains a bunch of folders, all of which contain a .go file that I will want to build, and I'm trying to create a Makefile that can accomplish this. These are the requirements I'm looking to fill:

1.) I want this to be dynamic so that the number of folders can grow and change, and I won't need to update the Makefile every time.

2.) I also want the .go files to be able to have different names than the folder that holds them (for example, if the folder is `lambda1` then the .go file shouldn't need to be named `lambda1.go`).

3.) Lastly, I want each binary to be output in the same folder that its source file is in.

This is what the folder structure looks like with the built binaries included:

```
lambdas
  lambda1
    --first.go
    --first (binary)
  lambda2
    --second.go
    -- second (binary)
  lamba3
    --third.go
    --third (binary)
  ...
```

This is what the actual build commands look like:

```
GOOS=linux go build -o lambdas/lambda1/first lambdas/lambda1/first.go
GOOS=linux go build -o lambdas/lambda2/second lambdas/lambda2/second.go
```

and then in a later step I need to zip that binary like this:

```
zip lambdas/lambda1/function.zip lambdas/lambda1/first
zip lambdas/lambda2/function.zip lambdas/lambda2/second
```

It seems like what I need is to loop through the `lambdas` directory, and for each directory, get the name of the .go file, and then using those dir paths and file names, I could create each build command.

I'm brand new to Makefiles and have been trying to figure this out for about a day now and am not having luck. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
# Find all the .go files under lambdas
GOFILES := $(shell find lambdas -name \*.go)

GOPROGS := $(GOFILES:%.go=%)
GOZIPS := $(GOPROGS:%=%.zip)

# We want to build all the progs and zips
all: $(GOPROGS) $(GOZIPS)

# How to build each prog from a .go file
$(GOPROGS): % : %.go
        GOOS=linux go build -o $@ $<

# How to build each zip from a prog file
$(GOZIPS) : %.zip : %
        zip $@ $<
```

I'm using [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html) here but you could use normal pattern rules as well.

Oh I didn't notice you want the zip files to have the same name.  This of course assumes that there will be only one `.go` file, and hence one program, in every directory?  Seems limited.

This is not so simple because the names don't match.  Although it could be done via separate rules if you really wanted to, the simplest thing to do is just put both the compile and zip into the same rule:

```
# Find all the .go files under lambdas
GOFILES := $(shell find lambdas -name \*.go)

GOPROGS := $(GOFILES:%.go=%)

# We want to build all the progs
all: $(GOPROGS)

# How to build each prog from a .go file
$(GOPROGS): % : %.go
        GOOS=linux go build -o $@ $<
        zip $(@D)/function.zip $@
```

Comment: I should point out that this uses GNU make features.  If you want your makefile to work with other versions of make, it will be a lot more work.

Comment: Thank you! This is great, I just tested it and works perfectly. If I wanted all of the zip files to have the same name, just "function.zip", would this be a simple change? I'm not sure how to do this myself atm, since the $@ in the zip step has the whole path including the binary name

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You want one zip file per directory, with the name `function.zip`?  Or you want one zip file at the top level, containing all the individual programs in it?

Comment: Yea one zip per directory, each one with the same name